# Trying to repair infected rpcss.dll in Vista causes black screen on bootup

Tags: windows, boot, windows-vista, malware

I ran the malware scanner Hitman Pro on a Windows Vista computer, and it detected that C:\Windows\system32\rpcss.dll was infected.  I uploaded the file to virustotal.com and its analysis said that 28 out of 53 signature databases report it is infected with a trojan/virus, so it is very likely infected.

I did a `sfc /scanfile=c:\Windows\system32\rpcss.dll`, and Windows said the file was corrupted and that it repaired the file and that I needed to restart.  After Vista booted up, all it showed was a black screen with the mouse pointer.  It never made it to the login screen.  I could move the mouse pointer around, but nothing else worked.  CTRL+ALT+DEL didn't do anything, and I had to do a hard power down and power on to restart the computer.

The same black screen with mouse pointer happened when I tried to boot Vista into Safe Mode.  Then I tried booting from the Dell Windows Vista DVD, and I tried the "Startup Repair" option, but it said it couldn't find any problems.  Running chkdsk didn't find any problems either.  So I used the System Restore option to go back to a restore point from yesterday, and the system was finally able to boot up to the login screen.  But the rpcss.dll file is still infected according to virustotal.com.

Any idea how to fix the rpcss.dll file and not run into the black screen problem?

Comment: Did you run `chkdsk C: /r` already?

Comment: Yes I ran chkdsk and it didn't find any problems.

Comment: Even with the `/r` switch, right? What's the hard disk model? Try scanning your system with [Windows Defender Offline](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline).

Answer (score 0):

boot from the [Windows Vista DVD or Windows Recovery Environment (F8)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-vista), open the command prompt and run this:

```
sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=c:\ /OFFWINDIR=c:\windows
```

Replace C: with the drive letter where you installed Windows.

Is sfc able to restore the infected file?

Comment: I did do a "sfc /scannow" an hour ago and it said there were corrupt files, but when I restarted I still got the black screen.  I didn't include the *offbootdir* and *offwindir* options though - apparently those are for offline repairs - what does "offline repair" mean?

Comment: the "off" means when the Windows is not booted. upload the CBS.log so that we can see which files are still corrupted

Comment: I uploaded everything in CBS.log from today: http://pastebin.com/UuHHViTh

Comment: according to the log, the rpcss.dll was restored, but the settings.ini from the Sidebar is still broken. so your blackscreen has other causes

Comment: @pacoverflow As previously commented, there's only a file which *appears* to be corrupted: `C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\settings.ini` It's actually a [documented false positive](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947595/en-us), and you can safely ignore it.

Comment: I ended up booting from the Vista DVD, opening a command prompt, and doing a "copy d:\windows\system32\rpcss.dll c:\windows\system32".  The D drive is the recovery drive.  Windows restarted fine, and I logged in and double checked the rpcss.dll on virustotal.com and it wasn't infected.  So far so good.  But then out of curiosity I tried "sfc /scanfile=c:\windows\system32\rpcss.dll" again and surprisingly it said the file was corrupt and told me to restart.  I restarted and once again got the black screen...

Comment: ... Then I went back to an infected restore point, re-copied the rpcss.dll from the recovery drive, and got the system working again.  But it's strange that Windows would think the original rpcss.dll copied from the recovery drive is corrupt.  I'm not going to run "sfc /scanfile" on it again, but it makes me wonder if I'll run into problems in the future if I ever have to do a "sfc /scannow" on the system.

Comment: the rpcss.dll was probable updated by a Windows update. So you can't use the old file from the DVD. Try the Inplace upgrade to repair Windows correctly: http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/88236-repair-install-vista.html